# How to select the tag of the latest non-unstable/release candidate version?

Tags: linux-kernel, git

I've downloaded the latest kernel sources:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
cd linux-stable
git tag -l | less
```

and picked v3.9.1.

```
git checkout -b v3.9.1
git branch --set-upstream v3.9.1 origin/master
```

, pulled the distribution:

```
git pull
```

and ran:

```
make kernelversion
```

which always outputs:

```
4.0.0-rc5
```

, an unstable version. How may I download v3.9.1(a stable version)?

Comment: Some background on what you are trying to do, please? If you just want a recent kernel, the easiest thing to do it is to get it from Debian itself.

Comment: You can specify the branch in clone.  `git clone -b v3.9.1 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`.  However, 3.9 is long gone.  The latest stable is 3.19.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run

```
git branch --set-upstream v3.9.1 origin/master
```

you're telling `git` that you want your local `v3.9.1` branch to track `master` on the remote. To get the remote `v3.9.1` you can simply do

```
git checkout v3.9.1
```

If you're using the repository you created previously, you'll need to delete your own `v3.9.1` branch first:

```
git checkout master
git branch -d v3.9.1
```

`git checkout v3.9.1` will put you in detached HEAD state, at the commit tagged `v3.9.1` on the remote (`v3.9.1` is a tag on the remote, not a branch). Once you're there you can create a local `v3.9.1` branch if you wish by running

```
git checkout -b v3.9.1
```

But whether or not you create a local branch, at this point

```
make kernelversion
```

should output

```
3.9.1
```

As [Devon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/50993/devon) points out you can do this in one shot when cloning the tree initially:

```
git clone -b v3.9.1 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

This works even though `v3.9.1` is a tag, and you end up in detached HEAD state as above.